# regular expression for validating a range of 1024 - 25600

Tags: regex

I came across all of the easy range validation like 1-99 or 3-1000 but I am not able to create a reg for the above requirement (1024 - 25600)any help will be greatly appreciated .... thanks

Comment: What could be a reason to do this with regex instead of simple operators? Would be nice to know?

Comment: This is not a problem to solve using regular expressions. Just split the range into two integers and test them.

Comment: Whatever language you are using, it would be better not to test those ranges using Regex. It would be a little ugly, and unreadable. Plus, it won't show your intentions clearly.

Comment: just to know: Who recommend you use regular expressions for this very difficult and not trivial task of range-validating?

Comment: See: http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range

Comment: @PatrickB. am working a code base where they are already using the regx for this kinda validation so have been asked to follow the suite .

Comment: @Martín Valdés de León : ll try to

Comment: Regexes are for matching patterns, not testing arithmetic properties.  Detect your string that looks like a number, and then test the number to see if it is in range in your host language.

Comment: You can use regex to check that the input only contains digits, or under a certain number of digits before converting to number to check for range.

Comment: Regular expressions are designed to match patterns and not values.

Comment: @BartKiers : thts awesome !!

Answer (score 6):

Regular expressions are not meant to evaluate numeric ranges. You were able to get away with that for ranges like 1-99 just because you needed to check number of digits, but they're not going to work to validate arbitrary numeric range.

Comment: http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range   thanks for the input but they do work !